# Keyboard shortcut for copying filepath in MsOffice 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013

For example, in Word2010, you can copy the document filepath pressing: `Alt`, `F`, `Tab` , `Ctrl+C`.

In Word 2013, the last `Ctrl+C` does not copy the filepath because then you have the options of:

a) Copy link to clipboard

b) Open link location

I tried the `application key` but it didn't work either. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complicated, but here it is...

`Alt`, `F`, `Tab`, `Enter`, `C`

You could just get a simple macro to do it, and assign a simple shortcut.

Comment: Thanks @pgr, it will work for the moment, although the spaces between the name show "%20" and alike.

Comment: Where will you be using that path? Because most places (Explorer, Browsers, etc) will interpret those `%20` correctly, so that might not be a problem.

Comment: Anywhere, maybe pasting it in e-mails to show where the file is in a shared drive, etc.

Comment: The only problem you'll have with those codes will be aesthetics and human readability. Technically speaking, they'll work fine. If one day you decide to go with a VBA solution (macro), you can clean up those codes easily (replace them back with the original characters).

Comment: Thanks @pgr, I mostly want this to create links and directly show the folder to other workmates. The macro would be more of a hassle than looking after the aesthetics. Thanks so much for your help!